# seaborn rugplot plot nothing in 0.10.0 version

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

Seaborn rugplot plot nothing in version 0.10.0

Same code works fine under 0.9.0 and I checked https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html to find out if there was an update regarding rugplot but there wasn't.

```
import seaborn
from matplotlib import pyplot
iris = seaborn.load_dataset('iris')

x = iris.petal_length.values

seaborn.rugplot(x)
pyplot.show()
```

[image: rugplot_0.9.0]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code with both Seaborn 0.9.0 and 0.10.0, and they both work fine. I can't reproduce the empty plot that you are getting. Is that all of your code?

[image]

Comment: Yes. That is all of my code. I think this is a problem related to version of matplotlib.

Comment: Do you have the most up to do version of matplotlib?

Comment: Yes. I uninstalled and reinstalled matplotlib to latest officially released version.